# How to use tags/{tags}/related

Tags: support, tags, related

I am new to stackapps. I am wondering how to apply `/tags/{tags}/related` to more than one tags. The [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-tags) does not give an example. I tried
`/2.0/tags/c,java/related?site=stackoverflow`, `/2.0/tags/c-java/related?site=stackoverflow`, and `/2.0/tags/{c,java}/related?site=stackoverflow` but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new to the API also, I think mostly multiple args are separated with `;`

Try `c;java`